# No matching function error when I try to throw an exception

Tags: c++, function, matching

I have this code:

```
class RepoException
{

public:

    RepoException(string& msg)
    {
        this->msg=msg;
    }

    string& getMsg()
    {
        return this->msg;
    }

private:

    string msg;
};

template<typename T>
class Repo 
{

public:

    Repo()
    {
        vector<T> elems;
    }

    void store(T elem) throw (RepoException)
    {
        for(int i =0; i<elems.size();i++)
        {
            if (elems[i]->getId() == elem->getId())
            {
                throw RepoException("There is a person with same id ");
            }

        }
        elems.push_back(elem);
    }
```

In the function `store`, when I try to throw the exception I get this error:

```
  Multiple markers at this line
    - candidates are:
    - no matching function for call to 'RepoException::RepoException(const
```

Why do I get this error?

Comment: Have you tried adding a version that takes `const` arguments?

Comment: Is this error at compile or run time? I also suggest making all exception classes derived from std::exception. Forests of exception classes makings handling difficult.

Comment: You can't pass a raw string with a `std::string &`, you need `std::string` or `std::string const &`.

Comment: @user3344003, definitely not runtime.

Comment: You'd think that but the question does not read that way. He says he's getting it when he "throw[s] the exception".

Comment: @user3344003 `no matching function for call to ...` errors are at compile time.

Comment: He's edited but chopped off the end of the message. That probably reads "&RepoException)"

Answer (score 0):

In a call

```
RepoException( "There is a person with same id ")
```

the parameter `"There is a person with same id "` is of type `const char []`. This cannot be used to convert into string, but it can if you write:

```
RepoException( const string& msg)
```

A good practice is to derive exceptions from std::exception, i.e [std::runtime_error](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/runtime_error).

Answer (score 0):

Your current code contains a lot of errors. Here's few:

- The `Repo` constructor is not doing what you think it's doing.
- `RepoException`'s constructor should accept a `const std::string&` or `std::string`
- `RepoException` should derive from `std::exception`
- You are throwing `RepoException` by value, but `RepoException` does not have a copy constructor

Taking a closer look at your code I think you really want to use an [`std::set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set), which will contain only unique values. It is also optimized to check if that value exists or not in the set:

```
template<typename T> using Repo = std::set<T>;
```